# C# PrinterSettings Invalid

Tags: c#, printing

In the following snippet, I get the default printer settings, and overwrite the PrinterName with a printer name selected from a combobox that has been populated from the InstalledPrinters property.

Then I set the number of copies to a small integer value.

```
public void Print(){
        CurrentPageIndex = 0;
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.DocumentName = "Report";
        printDoc.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = this.PrinterName;
        printDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = this.Copies;

        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("PrinterSettings");
        }

        ImageDimensions = new FrameDimension(RenderedImage.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
        FrameCount = RenderedImage.GetFrameCount(ImageDimensions);

        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPageHandler);

        printDoc.Print();
    }

    private void PrintPageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        RenderedImage.SelectActiveFrame(ImageDimensions, CurrentPageIndex);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(RenderedImage, new Point(0, 0));
        CurrentPageIndex++;
        e.HasMorePages = (CurrentPageIndex < 0);
    }
```

When I check the printersettings in the line `if(!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)`, I always get that the settings invalid.

I thought taking the default settings and changing the printer name and number of copies should give me valid PrinterSettings.

Comment: This is a printer driver problem.  Try updating the driver or pick another printer or ignore IsValid and see what you get.

Comment: Updating the driver unfortunately isn't an option. I tried ignoring IsValid, but then I get an error when I print. My accepted solution is to simply print to the standard printer.